# Does Ronon ever wear an earpiece?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

I've watched the entire *Stargate: Atlantis* series a couple of times over the years and don't ever recall seeing Ronon wear or use an earpiece, although I haven't watched all the shows looking specifically for this.

Does he use an earpiece like the rest of the crew? I realize his dreads would make it hard to see, but I don't ever see him tapping his ear to talk, wincing at static, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

Here's an image of him from the Season 2 episode *Conversion* with an earpiece (just before entering the cave with Iratus bug larva):

[image: Ronon Dex Conversion]

Here's another image of him with an earpiece in.  I can't seem to pinpoint which episode this is at the moment though I think that it is Season 5 (since his dreads look sewn in).

[image: Ronon with an earpiece]

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same and google'd it.  Found this site.  Just saw Ronon tap his ear and talk to McKay in Season 5, Episode 9 "Tracker".

Comment: Although this does offer some useful info, it would have been better made as a comment. I do appreciate that you have insufficient rep to do so (yet)